# Every time I install Magisk after a factory reset, I get back an old boot animation and theme. How?

Tags: factory-reset, themes, boot-animation, magisk

I have factory reset my phone a few times, but every time I install Magisk, I get back an old boot animation that I used from a custom ROM/Kernel I installed and I also get a custom Red accent color I installed. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magisk has fixed this error in v14.